# PostgreSQL 8.4: how to add locale to specified table/column, not all DB?

Tags: postgresql

I have one table (only one) among many others that need to be initialize with different locales (one locale per one column).

How to add such locale support to PostgreSQL 8.4? I do not know mechanism: edit configure files or edit existing tables or smth else?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible with 8.4. You need to upgrade to 9.1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you post that as an answer so it can be upvoted? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8.4 does not support per column collations (or collation "expressions" for comparing and sorting).

You will have to upgrade to 9.1 (which is a good idea anyway)